# Testing equivalence of means of Numpy MaskedArray instances raises attribute error

Tags: python, numpy

**Edit 1:**

So far it appears that this is a bug that was added somewhere between versions 1.8.1 and 1.9.2.  I have yet to track down the root cause.  In 1.8.1 `np.ma.MaskedArray.mean()` would return a scalar.  In 1.9.2 it is returning a zero dimensional MaskedArray.  This appears to only occur when `foo.mask` is set to `np.ma.nomask`.

**Edit 2:**

[I have submitted this as a bug here.](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5769)

I tried to track this issue down, but am having difficulty following the inheritance for `MaskedArray.mean()`.  Specifically, I am having difficulty with line 2711 in numpy/core/fromnumeric.py which appears to call back to `MaskedArray.mean()` when called with a `MaskedArray` instance.

**Original Question:**

I'm probably doing something funny here, but I can't seem to find the problem.  When I test the equivalence of the means of two different instances of `np.ma.MaskedArray` an `AttributeError` is raised.

**Creating the arrays:**

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: foo = np.ma.array([1,2,3,4])

In [3]: bar = np.ma.array([1,2,3,4])

In [4]: foo.mean()
Out[4]: 
masked_array(data = 2.5,
             mask = False,
       fill_value = 1e+20)


In [5]: bar.mean()
Out[5]: 
masked_array(data = 2.5,
             mask = False,
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

**Comparison of the arrays works fine:**

```
In [6]: foo == bar
Out[6]: 
masked_array(data = [ True  True  True  True],
             mask = False,
       fill_value = True)
```

**Testing equivalence of the means fails:**

```
In [7]: foo.mean() == bar.mean()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-3b824b0972e3> in <module>()
----> 1 foo.mean() == bar.mean()

/users/___/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.pyc in __eq__(self, other)
   3705                         mask = np.all([[f[n].all() for n in mask.dtype.names]
   3706                                         for f in mask], axis=axis)
-> 3707                 check._mask = mask
   3708         return check
   3709     #

AttributeError: 'numpy.bool_' object has no attribute '_mask'

In [8]: foo.mean() != bar.mean()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-0947fa5da1ed> in <module>()
----> 1 foo.mean() != bar.mean()

/users/___/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.pyc in __ne__(self, other)
   3738                         mask = np.all([[f[n].all() for n in mask.dtype.names]
   3739                                         for f in mask], axis=axis)
-> 3740                 check._mask = mask
   3741         return check
   3742     #
```

**Testing for larger or smaller of the means works fine:**

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.bool_' object has no attribute '_mask'

In [9]: foo.mean() >= bar.mean()
Out[9]: 
masked_array(data = True,
             mask = False,
       fill_value = True)


In [10]: foo.mean() <= bar.mean()
Out[10]: 
masked_array(data = True,
             mask = False,
       fill_value = True)
```

**Python version 2.7.2 with Numpy version 1.9.2:**

```
In [11]: np.__version__
Out[11]: '1.9.2'
```

It appears that in `np.ma.MaskedArray.__ne__()` the variable `check` is created by a line that looks like:

```
check = np.ndarray.__eq__(foo.filled(0), bar.filled(0)).view(type(foo))
```

which I would expect to return a new masked array.  However, since `np.ndarray.__eq__()` returns an instance of `np.bool_`.  attempting to make a `MaskedArray` view of the `check` simply produces another `np.bool_` instance.  The error occurs when the routine attempts to assign to `check._mask` since `np.bool_` does not have a `_mask` attribute.

Any ideas what is going on here?  A bug or stupidity on my part?

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5769; raised again in 2016 at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164773/numpy-ma-masked-array-mean-method-has-inconsitent-return-type