# numpy.ma (masked) array mean method has inconsitent return type

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array

I noticed that the [numpy masked-array mean method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.MaskedArray.mean.html#numpy.ma.MaskedArray.mean) returns different types when it probably should not:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.ma.masked_equal([1,1,0], value=0)
B = np.ma.masked_equal([1,1,1], value=0) # no masked values

type(A.mean())
#numpy.float64
type(B.mean())
#numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray
```

Other `numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray` methods seem to be consistent

```
type( A.sum()) == type(B.sum())
# True
type( A.prod()) == type(B.prod())
# True
type( A.std()) == type(B.std())
# True
type( A.mean()) == type(B.mean())
# False
```

Can someone explain this?

**UPDATE:** As pointed out in the comments

```
C = np.ma.masked_array([1, 1, 1], mask=[False, False, False])
type(C.mean()) == type(A.mean())
# True
```

Comment: If it returns a different type ONLY when you're not masking any values, then that isn't an inconsistency, that's just a special case... Have you checked the type of B immediately after calling masked_equal?

Comment: Note that if `C =np.ma.masked_array([1, 1, 1], mask=[False, False, False])`, then `type(C.mean())` is the same as `type(A.mean())`.

Comment: Interesting indeed

Answer (score 1):

`B.mask` starts with:

```
    if self._mask is nomask:
        result = super(MaskedArray, self).mean(axis=axis, dtype=dtype)
```

`np.ma.nomask` is `False`.

This is the case for your `B`:

```
masked_array(data = [1 1 1],
             mask = False,
       fill_value = 0)
```

For `A` the mask is an array that matches the `data` in size.  In `B` it is a scalar, `False`, and `mean` is handling that as a special case.

I need to dig a bit more to see what this implies.

```
In [127]: np.mean(B)
Out[127]: 
masked_array(data = 1.0,
             mask = False,
       fill_value = 0)

In [141]: super(np.ma.MaskedArray,B).mean()
Out[141]: 
masked_array(data = 1.0,
             mask = False,
       fill_value = 0)
```

I'm not sure that helps; there's some circular referencing between `np.ndarray` methods and the `np` function and the `np.ma` methods, that makes it hard to identify exactly what code is being used.  It like it is using the compiled `mean` method, but it isn't obvious how that handles the masking.

I wonder if the intent is to use

```
 np.mean(B.data) # or
 B.data.mean()
```

and the `super` method fetch isn't the right approach.

In any case, the same array, but with a vector mask returns the scalar.

```
In [132]: C
Out[132]: 
masked_array(data = [1 1 1],
             mask = [False False False],
       fill_value = 0)

In [133]: C.mean()
Out[133]: 1.0
```

====================

Trying this method without the `nomask` shortcut, raises an error after

```
        dsum = self.sum(axis=axis, dtype=dtype)
        cnt = self.count(axis=axis)
        if cnt.shape == () and (cnt == 0):
            result = masked
        else:
            result = dsum * 1. / cnt
```

`self.count` returns a  scalar in the `nomask` case, but a `np.int32` in the regular masking.  So the `cnt.shape` chokes.

`trace` is the only other masked method that tries this `super(MaskedArray...)` 'shortcut'.  There's clearly something kludgy about the mean code.

====================

Relevant bug issue: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5769

According to that the same question was raised here last year: [Testing equivalence of means of Numpy MaskedArray instances raises attribute error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689040/testing-equivalence-of-means-of-numpy-maskedarray-instances-raises-attribute-err)

Looks like there are a lot of masking issues, not just with `mean`.  There may be fixes in the development master now, or in the near future.