# Why are the return types of the numpy sum and mean function behaving differently when fed with a masked array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masked-array

Debugging a python package I've come across the following issue:

In the pathological case that I feed the numpy mean function with a masked array, the return type is a masked array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import numpy.ma as ma
>>> a=ma.array([1,2])
>>> np.mean(a)
masked_array(data = 1.5,
             mask = False,
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

while if I feed the sum function with the same masked array, the return type is a float:

```
>>> np.sum(a)
3
```

Does anybody have an idea if this behaviour is intended and if so, what's the reasoning behind?

Tested with python versions 2.7.12 and Python 3.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

With the example given in the `ma.mean` docs both return scalars

```
In [1217]: b = np.ma.array([1,2,3], mask=[False, False, True])
In [1218]: b.mean()
Out[1218]: 1.5
In [1219]: b.sum()
Out[1219]: 3
```

Your case is different in that the mask is a scalar `False`, not an array:

```
In [1220]: a=np.ma.array([1,2,3])
In [1221]: a
Out[1221]: 
masked_array(data = [1 2 3],
             mask = False,
       fill_value = 999999)
In [1222]: a.mean()
Out[1222]: 
masked_array(data = 2.0,
             mask = False,
       fill_value = 999999)
In [1223]: a.sum()
Out[1223]: 6
```

It really shouldn't make a difference.  I vaguely recall seeing a discussion of this.  I don't recall whether it was in another SO, or a bug issue.  It may also have been fixed.  We'd have to do some searching.  My numpy version is '1.11.0'

The problem is a line at the start at of the masked `mean`:

```
if self._mask is nomask:
   result = super(MaskedArray, self).mean(axis=axis, dtype=dtype)
```

`nomask` is scalar `False`; so in your `a` case it just tries to perform the regular numpy mean, without doing anything special with that mask.  But that tries to return a result of the same subclass as the input.

Changing `a` mask to an array will 'correct' the issue.

```
In [1247]: a.mask=[False,False,False]
```

==============

OK, the duplicate was hiding in the sidebar in plain sight

[numpy.ma (masked) array mean method has inconsitent return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164773/numpy-ma-masked-array-mean-method-has-inconsitent-return-type)

I found a bugissue last July, but no patch.